# How to improve Triangulated Irregular Network (TIN) display speed?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, dem, 3d-analyst, tin

I am preparing Triangulated Irregular Network for large area (5000 Sq Km) in ArcGIS, The TIN models takes too much time to open in ArcMap, and if I move or change anything again its starts to rendering, It takes too much time to do small changes, how to stop the rendering, and how to keep it in Builded TIN in ArcMap.

Number of Nodes in TIN is 3633846
Number of Triangles is 7267645

it takes three minutes to open fully.

Answer (score 3):

Work with "Terrain" in ArcGIS instead of standard TIN. Then you will have the option of saving several "resolutions" and your rendering will be less of a problem. When zooming out, it will show a rough resolution, when zooming in, the resolution will increase. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005v00000002000000.htm.